# $scope.dtInstance.reloadData() is not a function when called within an $interval

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am experiencing weird behaviour with AngularJS Datatables that I can't seem to find the source of the problem. On page load, my Datatable works and populates fine. I have a manual refresh button that calls `$scope.dtInstance.reloadData();` and that also works fine. However, I have setup an `$inverval` that fires every 60 seconds to automatically call the exact same function (`$scope.refreshWeights()`) and that seems to fail with an error of:

[image]

I have initialised my Datatable like so:

```
 $scope.dtInstance = {};
    let refreshInterval = 60000; // Every 60 seconds
    let refreshPromise;

    // Build the datatable
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
        .fromFnPromise( function() {

            return WeighBridgeService.get( moment( $scope.searchDate ).format( 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) )
                .then( function( response ) {

                    if( response.status === 200 ) {

                        $scope.weights = response.data.weights;

                        return $scope.weights;

                    } else {

                        return {};

                    }

                }, function( error ) {

                    return {};

                });

        })
        .withDOM( 'lfrtip' )
        .withBootstrap()
        .withPaginationType( 'full_numbers' )
        .withOption('createdRow', function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
            $compile( angular.element( row ).contents() )( $scope );
        })
        .withOption('fnRowCallback', dtRowCallback)
        ...
        ...
```

And then I have my controller code to handle the refresh:

```
$scope.refreshWeights = function() {   // <== This works fine when I press the refresh button

    // Redraw the datatable
    $scope.dtInstance.reloadData( null, true );

};



// Refresh the data every minute
refreshPromise = $interval( function() {  // <== This throws an error every 60 seconds

    $scope.refreshWeights();

}, refreshInterval );
```

And my HTML is like so:

```
    <div class="panel">

        <div class="panel-heading">

            <button class="btn pull-right mt-10" ng-click="refreshWeights()"><span class="far fa-sync-alt" ng-class="{ 'fa-spin': refreshing }"></span> Refresh</button>

            <div>

                <h1>Daily Weight Readings</h1>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <label class="mr-10">Date:</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="width: 264px; display: inline-block" type="date" ng-model="searchDate" ng-change="refreshWeights()"/>

            <hr>

            <table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="table table-hover cursor-pointer" width="100%"></table>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I have the exact same code in another web application and that works fine without error. I have copied all the code over, checked and double checked version numbers and everything seems the same. I can't find what I have overlooked here.

When I `console.log($scope.dtInstance)` within the `$scope.refreshWeights()` function, it shows me that `$scope.dtInstance` is empty just before it calls the `reloadData()` function, however, it shows as populated afterwards.

Also, even though I am getting the above error, it is still calling the HTTP request and returning data on `response.data`.

Comment: I have returned my code back to bare basics and followed the example on the `angular-datatables` website exactly and I still get the error. I can see that the datatable is reloading new data, but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

please add `$scope.dtInstance.rerender();`  instead of  **reloadData**

and to refesh datatable use

```js
function myTimeoutFunction()
{
    $scope.dtInstance.rerender();
}
myTimeoutFunction();
setInterval(myTimeoutFunction, 1000);
```

Comment: Okay, I implemented this code snippet and whilst my datatable will now redraw every time the `interval` executes, it still shows the same error: `$scope.dtInstance.rerender is not a function`. So it it redrawing or reloading the datatable fine, but something else is causing the error to be thrown.